# Undefined array key; Trying to access array offset on value of type null ; foreach() argument must be of type array|object

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays, file

I've try everything, can someone help me? Im getting 3 error on: foreach()...

PHP: 8.0
MYSQL: 5.1

```html
foreach($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name) {
    $file_name=$_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$key];
    $pasta_dir = "../www/layout/diario_de_obra/upload_img/";
    $diretorio_img = $pasta_dir . $file_name;
    $arquivo = $_FILES["userfile"]['tmp_name'][$key];
    move_uploaded_file($arquivo, $diretorio_img);
    print($file_name." enviado com sucesso!");
}



<div enctype="multipart/form-data">  <!-- action="upload" method="post"  accept=”image/* class="simagem" -->
     <label>Selecione as fotos de hoje aqui:
        <input id="image-file" type="file" name="userfile[]">
        <input id="image-file" type="file" name="userfile[]">
     </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with your example I came up with this

```html
<form action="imageUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>  <!-- action="upload" method="post"  accept=”image/* class="simagem" -->
        <label>Selecione as fotos de hoje aqui:
            <input id="image-file" type="file" name="userfile[]">
            <input id="image-file" type="file" name="userfile[]">
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">click me</button>
</form>
```

Now your PHP started working.

Comment: Thanks Guido, in some hella way it was my pc... i just put in the host and worked as it was doing before.